# I am trying to use an if statement in python to display a dictionary but it skips straight to the else block

Tags: python

```
Database = {"name" : "Nicholas"}
Print ("welcome to database\n")
Print ("Enter 1 to display database\n")
Print ("Enter 2 to delete database\n")
X = input("make entry here:")

if x == 1:
    Print(database)
else:
    Print(" error")
```

Comment: input function returns a string.  try converting to int before the comparison with: `x = int(input("make entry here:")`

Answer (score 2):

On top of the typo errors that are present in your code involving capitalization of `print` and variable names, even after you fix the syntax errors, the control flow of the code will still not go to the `if` branch. This is because `input` method in Python will store a string value into variable `x`, even if the user input is `1`. Since `1 == “1”` leads to false, you will always get to the `else` branch.

Here is a way to get the control flow of the code to pass through the `if` branch, after all the syntax errors are fixed.

```
Database = {"name" : "Nicholas"}
print ("welcome to database\n")
print ("Enter 1 to display database\n")
print ("Enter 2 to delete database\n")
x = input("make entry here:")

if x == "1":
    print(Database)
else:
    print(" error")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is looking at x but your input is saved in a variable called X. Case matters.

Answer (score 0):

Python is case sensitive, so here you defined capital `X` but you didn't `x`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check against string, not int:

```
database = {"name" : "Nicholas"}
print ("welcome to database\n")
print ("Enter 1 to display database\n")
print ("Enter 2 to delete database\n")
x = input("make entry here:")

if x == "1":
    print(database)
else:
    print(" error")
```

Check it here: https://www.online-python.com/wbRd69MgYO

Answer (score 0):

Couple of issues.

1. input function always returns string. You need to convert into int
   like

   ```
   x = int(input("make entry here !!"))
   ```
2. You are storing return value of input() in 'X' but if condition is
   checking 'x' value which is wrong. Python is case sensitive.